# HTTP calls 404?

Tags: android, angular, rest, ionic3

I am having issues with most API calls going to our Magento 2 website, and keeps returning a 404 error to an Android device.

I have no issues with these API calls from using Ionic Serve, nor from Postman.

**ionic.config.json**

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "app_id": "f82ad91b",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "https://{url}/index.php/rest/V1"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my providers, I do switch out the paths accordingly to device:

**providers/foo/bar.ts**

```
private apiUrl:string;

/**
 * @public
 * @constructor
 */
constructor(
    public http: HttpClient,
    public platform: Platform,
    public storage: Storage,
    private authProvider: AuthenticateProvider,
    private catalogProvider: CatalogProvider) {

    if(this.platform.is('core') || this.platform.is('mobileweb')){
        this.apiUrl = '/api';
    } else {
        this.apiUrl = 'https://{url}/index.php/rest/V1';    
    }
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
```

**UPDATE - 2018-05-23**

- One thing that I noticed with the error message is that these 404 errors are giving me a HTML response looking like a 503 error page.
- Noticed that in the response headers, using Chromes inspect tools, that the bad responses are also adding a `content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests`. I am sending the requests with a HTTPS url, and the server-side is HTTPS. Not sure what is going on with this.

**UPDATE - 2018-05-24**

- The iOS build works though I have to use UIWebView, but that detail is irrelevant to this question.
- Added a CSP tag to the index.html file, and that did not make any changes for the Android app.

Comment: I had most of these issues, first of all, are you sure the IP address is running remotely ? android device may required a different config as you already know.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, are you sure of passing valid auth token while calling APIs?

Comment: @YashPatadia Yes, its a valid auth token as some API calls do go through while 90% of my calls are 404'd.

Comment: So, I can't make out what you might be doing wrong from what you've posted, but I can recommend an excellent debugging tool that I often use for these situations, it's [Telerik Fiddler](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid)